# Android - How can I make my system overlay window have the same dimension on different screens

Tags: android, dimensions

I made a system overlay window that always stays on top of other apps.
The width of the screen is 'MATCH_PARENT' and I want from the height to cover a certain area of the screen but my problem is that the height won't be same on different screens.

Here is my code:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                1500,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

How can can I make that 1500p be the same on different screens?
Thanks.

Comment: What about using getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels to get screenHeight?

Comment: How should i use it? thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Replace 1500 with getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels.

Comment: Just tried but it covers the whole screen, I just want to cover most of it. Any other options?

Comment: (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels* 0.8f) You can adjust it to fit your need.

Comment: Okay! I'm kinda there but I don't know how to adjust it?

Comment: What's the size you want it to be?

Comment: The equivalent of 1500 px, I set it to 0.866f am I right?

Comment: Why do you need 1500 px?

Comment: It's an imageView that needs a height of 1500 (approximately)  to be fully displayed.

Comment: I don't understand that system overlay window that always stays on top of other apps.What's the meaning?

Comment: It's a window remains on the top of every app as a service you can have have transparent or in another color. Sorry I'm not good at explaining. Here is the refence if you want to know more  [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)

Comment: Why do you need 1500px? A image can be showed in any size. A phone  usually has a height of 2000px.Do you want to cover all the screen?If you want to cover half of screen,just use (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels* 0.5f).

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken for something else, I ended up setting to 0.86 and it fits perfectly. Anyways, I appreciate your help, it was really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by tiny sunlight:

```
(int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels* 0.8f)
```

you have to replace the desired dimensions parameter with this and adjust the 0,8F 
to the desired measurements.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a dimension resource dimens.xml files with the window height dimension:

```
<dimen name="window_height">1500dp</dimen>
```

Then assign the dimension to the window height by calling the getRecources().getDimension() from the context like so:

```
int height = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.window_height);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            height,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: Just tried it but the gradle-build sends " Error:(5, 5) String types not allowed (at 'window_height' with value '1500p')." how can get past this?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, it covers the whole screen. I even got context error in  "context.getResouces()..." so I changed it to " (int) getResouces()...". can that be the reason?

Comment: Feel free to reduce the dimension to smaller value such as 300dp and try again and adjust it until the value you wanted. If your window is an Activity then can leave out the context just `(int) getResouces()...` will do

Comment: I ended up using @tiny sunlight's suggestion it, it was the one I was in need of. But thanks for the help, I appreciate it!